# Displaying a table next to a fixed width span

Tags: html, css

I have a html `<table>` that have dynamic width (changes with window size), and a fixed width `<span>` (500px).

I want to display both next to each other so that both would fill the whole width of the parent container

I want to do so only using CSS (not js)

I have been playing around with CSS but it seems to be ruining the table's width

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
   <table class='table'>....</table>
   <span class='span'>....</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   ......
}

.table {
  .....
}

.span {
   width: 500px;
   display: inline-block; //or block if neccessary
}
```

Comment: The only way I am aware of to do such a thing is to use `display: table-cell`...

Comment: yeah but should i display the "table" as "table-cell"

Comment: Create a jsfiddle so we know whats going on

Comment: No, but you could wrap it in a div that you display as table-cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may give a try with the [`table-layout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) propertie to `.container` and `span`.

Browsers should create themselves the element missing to produce the first table-cell.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HmDql)**

```
span {
  display:table-cell;
  width:500px;
  border:solid;
}
table {
  border:solid;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}
.container {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

This should work

because of **[`table-layout:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)**

and because browser should create themselves the missing element (like a `tbody` is always produced in a `<table>` when missing or when in a document is missing either  tags like `html` or `body` ).

Comment: Feel free to improve answer with links related to browser fixing markup  of document unproperly coded

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/93grC/)

css

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
}
table {
    width: calc(100% - 500px);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
}
/* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
th {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
td, th {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
}
.span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

html

```
<div class='container'>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>etc</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Gaurav</td>
                <td>Singh</td>
                <td>etc</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gaurav</td>
                <td>Singh</td>
                <td>etc</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> <span class='span'>....</span>

</div>
```